# Exc Bad Instruction in chieldViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have a problem when using PageMenuController,

In this [site](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController) the instruction is to add `ContainerView` into my View and embed my controller class into my View

this is my code:

testViewController

```
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestTableViewController") as! TestTableViewController
viewController.title = "Menu title"

let viewController1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Test1TableViewController") as! Test1TableViewController
viewController1.title = "Menu title"

let viewControllers = [viewController, viewController1]

let pagingMenuController = self.childViewControllers.first as! PagingMenuController
pagingMenuController.delegate = self

options.menuHeight = 60
options.menuDisplayMode = .Standard(widthMode: .Flexible, centerItem: true, scrollingMode: .PagingEnabled)
options.menuItemMode = .None
pagingMenuController.setup(viewControllers, options: options)
```

but I got an error in `self.childViewControllers.first as! PagingMenuController`, the error message is `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

I think the error is not from the `PagingMenuController` , please help me how to identify the error ?

Comment: First print the `self.childViewControllers` in your console and check which controllers you are getting!

Comment: @AshishKakkad when I try to print `self.childViewControllers.first` its said that it was `nil Optional(<testapp.testViewController: 0x7fc3f1ebd760>)` but if I try to print `self.childViewControllers` the result is my controller that I put the code above `[<testapp.testViewController: 0x7ff9d0fa6f00>]`